# How to use IMPORTXML with Google Sheets for multiple results with each one being in a different column?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this code:

```
=IMPORTXML(CA1,"//div[@class='1a']/div[@class='1b']/div[@class='1c']/img[@class='1d']/@src 
| //div[@class='2a']/span[@class='2b'] 
| //div[@class='3a']/span[@class='3b'] 
| //div[@class='4a']/span[@class='4b'] 
| //div[@class='5a']/span[@class='5b'] 
| //div[@class='6a']/span[6] 
| //div[@class='7a']/span[8] 
| //a/@title")
```

in 1 line:

```
=IMPORTXML(CA1,"//div[@class='1a']/div[@class='1b']/div[@class='1c']/img[@class='1d']/@src | //div[@class='2a']/span[@class='2b'] | //div[@class='3a']/span[@class='3b'] | //div[@class='4a']/span[@class='4b'] | //div[@class='5a']/span[@class='5b'] | //div[@class='6a']/span[6] | //div[@class='7a']/span[8] | //a/@title")
```

The function works and returns the following:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

The issue is that the output is in rows.

I need it to be in columns, something like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rVngBNR6zG1-R1wgT5WADDvT7jmWKICh7odH-47cL8w/edit?usp=sharing

etc...(blank cell is for values that are not there).

I tried TRANSPOSE, INDEX etc...

I also tried to repeat the IMPORTXML in different columns and only call for the div that I need but because the content changes dynamically on refresh, the output is not matched in each column.

How can I call all the parts of the page that I need with IMPORTXML while breaking them down into columns like the table example above?

Comment: Please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with data so that contributors can try their formulas.

Comment: @doubleunary I would it's just sensitive info and idk what website I can replicate this from

Comment: Just put some static data in Sheet1 that looks like your `importxml()` results, and show in Sheet2 how you would like to organize that data.

Comment: @doubleunary I did that, not sure if this is what you're looking for. I would like to add that I found a certain loophole sort of.....I would importxml in sheet1 let's say and it would spit the items in a row and then in sheet2 i would query the items one by one column by column. the only problem is that then the columns don't match, because some items have 8 rows and some have 7 so i need the query to add a blank cell where there is no value from import or when import doesnt find the span to add a blank cell.

Comment: Your sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." To best get help, please share it with "can edit" rights as explained in [these instructions](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684). Post back in this thread with the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this monster:

`=arrayformula( query( query( iferror( if( {1,1,0}, floor( mod(row(A:A)-{1,1},{9^9, 8}), {8,1} ),  transpose( split( regexreplace( query( transpose( query( transpose( importxml(CA1, "//div[@class='1a']/div[@class='1b']/div[@class='1c']/img[@class='1d']/@src | //div[@class='2a']/span[@class='2b'] | //div[@class='3a']/span[@class='3b'] | //div[@class='4a']/span[@class='4b'] | //div[@class='5a']/span[@class='5b'] | //div[@class='6a']/span[6] | //div[@class='7a']/span[8] | //a/@title") & char(9)), "", 9^9 ) ), "", 9^9 ), "\s+$", "" ), char(9) & " ", ) ) ) ), "select max(Col3) where Col3 <> '' group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0 ), "offset 1", 0 ) )`

Comment: the code divides rows into columns but unorganized. 1 can be in 3 and 4 can be in 8.